# HTML tooltip dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below html line,

Origional Code :

```
 <td width="9%" height="5%">
     <p class="idnumber" title="{{val.customerTypeDescNM}}">
     {{val.customerTypes}}</p>
 </td>


  <td width="9%" height="5%">
       <p class="idnumber" title="FTG,EMA,CAS">FTG,EMA,CAS</p>
  </td>
```

What I am stuck in here is, If I move the cursor on this td, I am getting "FTG,EMA,CAS" this as on title tag which is correct, but I want if my cursor is on FTG only, it should show me FTG in title tag. I am using angular js for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic Span

```
  <td width="9%" height="5%">
    <span title="{{val.customerTypeDescNM[$index]}}" ng-repeat="item in val.customerType.split(',') track by $index">{{item}}</span>
     </td>
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, Thank you for the answer.
Actually, the data I am showing in td is coming from "customer type" scope and description is coming coming from other scope, So how Can I handle it ?

Comment: Actually, the thing answer everyone is posting here is to handle static but in your case it is dynamic so, I have chosen dynamic spans instead of static.

Comment: Post your question again with the layout you are expecting or if you have two arrays you may use the track by $index

Comment: my values are coming dynamically, you can see in above my code, in "val.customerTypes", I am getting "FTG,EMA,CAS" but its description is diffetennt, which is coming from other "val.customerTypeDescNM", where FTG has different tooltip named "Fitgee", EMA has different tooltip name "Emerson" lie that.

Comment: yes, like here in yoor answer , you have used ng-repaet for val.customerTypeDescNM which should be come for title

Comment: I made a change in my answer it will be like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168181/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-angular-newpiee).

Comment: yes, now its is working, but I am getting first alphabet only in title tag, insted of full word

Comment: customerTypeDescNM is array or string?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<p>` tag, you can have 3 separate `span` tags with an individual item and separate title. You don't need angular for that.

```html
<td width="9%" height="5%">
       <span class="idnumber" title="FTG">FTG,</span>
       <span class="idnumber" title="EMA">EMA,</span>
       <span class="idnumber" title="CAS">CAS</span>
  </td>
```

Comment: hi kkk, thank you for the reply, but my values are coming dynamically, you can see in above my code, in "val.customerTypes", I am getting "FTG,EMA,CAS" but its description is diffetennt, which is coming from other "val.customerTypeDescNM", where FTG has different tooltip named "Fitgee", EMA has different tooltip name "Emerson" lie that.

Answer (score 0):

Add title attribute to each text:

```html
<td width="9%" height="5%">
  <p class="idnumber" title="FTG,EMA,CAS">
    <span title="FTG">FTG<span>,
    <span title="EMA">EMA</span>,
    <span title="CAS">CAS</span>
  </p>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, You need separate span tags with title tags for each. You may have to use ng-repeater for this.

```
<td width="9%" height="5%">
  <p class="idnumber" title="{{val.customerTypeDescNM}}">
    <span ng-repeat="tag in val.customerTypes.split(',')" title="tag">
      {{tag}}
    </span>
  </p>
</td>
```